# If I move out of the SMS sandbox will aws will charge extra charge for sending sms through aws sns or the same pricing will be charged

Tags: amazon-web-services, codeigniter

Actually I'm trying to send OTP for new signup user in codeigniter 3. I wanted to know whether I will be charged more If I move out of SMS sandbox in aws sns So that I can send to any user who are signing up in web page

I need  clarigication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon SNS pricing is available at: [Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS) Pricing | Messaging Service | AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/pricing/)

There is no difference in pricing between Sandbox and Production.